# Topological Sort in Java using DFS

Tags: java, topological-sort

I like to know is my current implementation of topological sort using DFS in directed graph is correct. I have used 2d array to represent a graph and deque for stack. Please share your knowledge with me as I am still learning graph theory, The codes are as follows:

```
public void topSort (int[][] edges)
{
    HashSet<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
    ArrayDeque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque();
    for (int i:edges[0] ) {
        if(visited.add(i))
            deque.add(i);
    }
    for (int i:edges[1] ) {
        if(visited.add(i))
            deque.add(i);
    }
    while (!deque.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.print(deque.removeFirst() +" ");

    }
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    //edge list


     int [][] edgeList={
        {1,1, 2,2, 4,4},
        {2, 4,3,4,3,5 }
    };
    TopologicalSort ts = new TopologicalSort();
    ts.topSort(edgeList);

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need to create graph when you call topologicalSort? Your function now has two responsibilities, to create graph and then run top sort. Deque is correct data structure for stack but i would stick with an interface rather than a class like `Deque<Integer> stack = ...`. Do you really need HashSet? Will you get dupe edges by using an array in a directed graph?

Comment: Updated. Hashset is O(1) access, just my preference

Comment: Array can be O(1) too since you edge id can be array index. Remember you are paying cost from memory (primitive vs wrapper) and operation perspective (maintaining/adding/removing from set).

Comment: @SMA suppose the inputs are given in this manner Jobs= [1,2,3] and prerequisites = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,2]]. In this case you would have to create the graph first using some custom class if java is used for implementation and then apply dfs.